# How to merge subfolders in libraries?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-libraries

I have managed to group folders using
[Can I get rid of the Windows 7 libraries folder dropdowns?](https://superuser.com/questions/94382/can-i-get-rid-of-the-windows-7-libraries-folder-dropdowns)

But now I see 3 folders all called "Soft"

[image]

Currently this library includes:

1. D:\Me
2. E:\Shared
3. F:\Test

The last one is added to see if it will merge the folders.

The folder structure for them is like this:

```
D: 
    Me
        Soft
E:
    Shared
        Drivers
        Soft
F:
    Test
        Soft
```

What do I need to do to get the "Soft" folders to combine into one merged folder?

Info:

- Windows 7 Ultimate x64
- Indexing service disabled

Comment: Perhaps make a "Soft" library and add those specific folders to it?

Comment: @techie007 what do you mean?

Comment: Make a new library, named something like "Soft" (for example).  Add those specific folders to that specific library. :)

Comment: @techie007 oh, sorry (wow I must be slow today) yes, I did that, but the folders within "soft" don't merge in that case, I wonder if there is some alternative Explorer program that does this? Although I also had thoughts of using symlinks everywhere to organize my folders across the 6 hard disks that I have.

Answer (score -3):

Under Library Properties, choose to organise as General Items

Comment: Doesn't sound like a working solution... besides, in my Win7 here it's "Optimize this library for...", not "Organise".

Comment: For sake of being new and for improvement, we're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer: please explain why you're recommending it as a solution.